# Linking javascript with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just learning about html, css, and javascript through codeacademy. I wanted to try and practice what I learned by creating a website without the codeacademy environment. The problem I'm having is linking my javascript to my html. I have three files in a folder: index.html, style.css, and script.js. I'm setting it up just as I learned, the website is loading fine, but the javascript never works for some reason. Any reason why? Here's my html and js:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    MESSAGE: <input type="text" name="message" value="Type your text here!">
    </form>
    <button>Add!</button><br/>
    <div id="messages"></div>
</body>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        var toAdd = $("input[name=message]").val();
        $('#messages').append("<p>" + toAdd + "</p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: You aren't including jQuery anywhere.

Comment: You should take a look at the error that was popping in your browser's console: `undefined variable $` or something like that. It usualy shows up when jQuery isn't included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include jquery (*before including your script.js*)

```
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
```

Comment: @a.mpeters, is that the correct path to "script.js"?  I ask because you're right, that code is fine, and all the answers provided so far are correct.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't included jQuery, codecademy does this for you, you can either download a local file [here](http://jquery.com/download/), then include it like your script.js:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or just link to the CDN like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is written using jQuery syntax, but you have not included the jQuery library anywhere.  Add jQuery before your script and you should be fine.

I would recommend using a CDN.  Add this line just before your script tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

**Edit:** At sircapsalot's behest, a CDN is a Content Delivery Network. [Read why using a CDN is a good idea](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

Comment: OP is just learning HTML, CSS, etc.. how do you expect them to know what a CDN is :P

Comment: @sircapsalot, I thought of spelling it out, but I knew this would be a speed race to get the answer in.  (And as it was, I still came second to pXL...not fast enough!)  I've now provided a definition and a helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the actual JQuery lib as well:

Add this before your script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answers before this one. You should first include your jQuery like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**But here's a tip**. Whenever you include jQuery on your webpage you should always first download it and then include it. This will give you a benefit that even when a user loses his/her internet connection the jQuery will still work but on the other side if you include it from the Google APIs the script will stop working when he/she will lose her internet connection.

You could download jQuery here: http://jquery.com/download/

You can include it this way(depending on what name you saved it with):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```